# How do I use signal handling to force reboot on application crash/hang on Linux?

Tags: c, embedded-linux

I have an application I wrote in C running on a Linux device server. If the application crashes or hangs, I'd like for the system to reboot. The device server came with a sample app that I think implements this functionality, but I'm not sure. By taking from it what seemed to implement this functionality, I have the following skeleton:

```
int terminate=0;

int main () {

  struct sigaction     sigact;

  sigact.sa_handler = sighandler;
  sigemptyset(&sigact.sa_mask);
  sigact.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGTERM,&sigact,0); 

  while (terminate == 0) 
  {
    // my main application functions
  }

  SDK_reboot();  // reboots my device server

}

void sighandler(int sig)
{
  if (sig == SIGTERM)
    terminate = 1;
}
```

I basically want to understand what is going on in the above code and, if necessary, alter it to fulfill my needs. Is 'sigaction(SIGTERM,&sigact,0);' the line that causes SIGTERM to be raised in response to my application hanging or crashing? If no, what would be the correct code? Also, is the above, in general, a good way to implement reboot on application crash/hang? Or am I way off track? Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: *"If the application crashes or hangs, I'd like for the system to reboot"* - Maybe that is common practice with micro-kernels and/or Windows, but bad practice for a protected kernel like Linux.  It's the rare case that a user program can actually freeze the whole system, and the proper fix would not be "rebooting". Why would you terminate unrelated daemons just because one process is hung?

Comment: There is only one application running on this little box. It lives to run this application--so rebooting could work just fine since it's good for it to reboot periodically anyway. But obviously I'd rather do things the right way--which I'd do if I knew what that was. Please share if you know.

Comment: You have one user app (for now), but there are probably system processes.  I have not used it, but maybe PCD, Process Control Daemon, could be part of the solution to avoid rebooting: http://www.rt-embedded.com/blog/pcd-process-control-daemon/  *"it's good for it to reboot periodically"* - That's a Windows mentality.  Unix & Linux systems have a reputation of having system uptimes measured in months not days.

Comment: Not really any particular mentality when you ideally need something to run for 25 years without human interference. Across the multiple boxes I have out in the field I don't observe it freezing up more than once every few months if that so ya months up time is great which is why I chose what I did, but I still need it to stay up and don't see rebooting every few months as a problem that requires installing extra monitoring software taking up room on this little box. But thanks I'll look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most reliable way to restart the board is to use a hardware watchdog timer. 
This solution will efficiently detect application crashes and hangs.

Embedded linux kernel usually contains watchdog driver (/dev/watchdog). Rebuild the kernel with watchdog support enabled.

Inside the application open /dev/watchdog, and keep writing to it often enough to keep the kernel from resetting, at least once per minute. Each write delays the reboot time another minute. After a minute of inactivity the watchdog hardware will cause the reset. (see http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog)

With reference to your code, you can open /dev/watchog as soon as the application started, then write to it inside a while loop. This will be true if the application has only one thread. If more threads, you need to come up with something a little more tricky.

There is also a way to detect the application crash. Main idea is the same, as in that solution: https://superuser.com/questions/223449/auto-restart-process-on-crash. The script can be rewritten in C. It involves the use of fork(), execve() waitpid().

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to use watchdog to begin with because it makes so much more sense to my simple mind and also perhaps to my simple application. So thank you for giving me confidence in this direction. I found the following two links to be very helpful with code examples that I will be able to use. (1) http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/watchdog-api.txt (2) http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/watchdog/src/watchdog-simple.c

Answer (score 0):

No, not SIGTERM, but SIGCHLD. In other words, the loop terminates when one of main's forked child processes exits.

This looks like a part of an application that forks the actual "worker process" and reboots if it exits. Note: a *hang* does not exit. This won't detect infinite loops or other hangs.

Comment: Is there a best practice way to detect hangs (I have a lot of socket open/close/read/write stuff that I am concerned may hang at some point.) and reboot on detection that you could point me toward?

Comment: If I just change SIGCHILD to SIGTERM would that work? As in 'sigaction(SIGTERM,&sigact,0);' instead of 'sigaction(SIGCHILD,&sigact,0);'?

Comment: No. A SIGTERM must be raised explicitly by calling `raise()` or sending the SIGTERM signal, while a `SIGCHLD` is generated by the kernel when a child exits. A SIGTERM is not generated when a program crashes; a `SIGSEGV` however is generated by the kernel if the program tries to access memory it shouldn't (*"crashes"*).